# Error 403 when making a POST request with Axios on a specific API URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, http, axios

I am using Axios within the Nodejs environment to make a request to get data, but when i'm using POST request with a content type 'application/x-www-form-unlencoded' i receive a response with error 403. Where is the problem in this HTTP request?, because with other tools it works for me. Here is an example of what i'm doing:

```
const axios = require('axios');

(async () => {
  try {

    let res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      baseURL: 'https://www3.animeflv.net',
      url: '/api/animes/search',
      data: 'value=tokyo',
      headers: { 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)', 
                 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`);
    console.log(res.data.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response);
  }
})();
```

When i execute this, the response of the API is this:
[image]

Also when i make the POST request with curl command in Linux, the response is successful, as shown below:
[image]

Comment: I think you need to add the content-type header to your axios request using `headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is working fine, because if you look at the "data" part of the response (`console.error(error.response.data);`) you get, you can see that you receive a "Check your browser" HTML webpage, that the browser should have rendered.

You get the same response if you are using an API Client like Insomnia ([Screenshot of the request in Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVQwS.png)).

Maybe you have to use another api, or spawn a [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) that executes curl to make the request, just like you did on the command line.